# How to fix UnrecognizedPropertyException with reading from JSON?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

I have an entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meals")
public class Meal extends AbstractNamedEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull(message = "Price must be added")
    private Integer price;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    public Meal() {
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

When I'm testing my controllers with the test data:

```
public class MealTestData {
    private static final Integer START_SEQ = 100000;

    public static final Meal MEAL_1 = new Meal(START_SEQ + 6, "ChickenBurger set", 300, RESTAURANT_1);
    public static final Meal MEAL_2 = new Meal(START_SEQ + 7, "CheeseBurger set", 400, RESTAURANT_1);
    public static final Meal MEAL_3 = new Meal(START_SEQ + 8, "FishBurger set", 500, RESTAURANT_1);
}
```

I get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid read array from JSON:
>   '[{"id":100006,"name":"ChickenBurger
>   set","price":300,"date":"2020-01-26"},{"id":100007,"name":"CheeseBurger
>   set","price":400,"date":"2020-01-26"},{"id":100008,"name":"FishBurger
>   set","price":500,"date":"2020-01-26"}]';
>
> Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "date" (class ru.topjava.graduation.model.Meal),
>   not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "price", "id", "name"]) 
>   at [Source: (String)"[{"id":100006,"name":"ChickenBurger
>   set","price":300,"date":"2020-01-26"},{"id":100007,"name":"CheeseBurger
>   set","price":400,"date":"2020-01-26"},{"id":100008,"name":"FishBurger
>   set","price":500,"date":"2020-01-26"}]"; line: 1, column: 62] (through
>   reference chain: ru.topjava.graduation.model.Meal["date"])

Which is the reason and how to fix it? I can't ignore that field in my tests

Both getter and setter for the field "date" are presented:

```
public LocalDate getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have @JsonIgnore annotation on 'date' field:

```
@JsonIgnore
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
```

but this field is present in input json:

```
{"id":100006,"name":"ChickenBurger set","price":300,"date":"2020-01-26"},
```

So either remove default value generation or switch setting for ObjectMapper like this:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```